# Имитация нажатия на радио кнопку при нажатии на другое поле

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такой код

```html
<div id="some" class="some">
  <label for="some">Заголовок</label>
  <p>
    <label>
           <input type="radio" class="input_radio" name="some_radio" value="0" 
           checked="checked" /> 
           <span class="radio-custom"></span>
        <span class="label">Выбрать 0</span>
     </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" class="input_radio" name="some_radio" value="1"> 
     <span class="radio-custom"></span>
     <span class="label">Выбрать 1 </span>
        <input type="text" class="input" name="price" value="">
    </label>
  </p>
</div>
```

Подскажите, как реализовать автоматическую установку второй радиокнопки при нажатии на поле `input`?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var input = document.getElementsByClassName('input')[0],
  inputRadio = document.getElementsByClassName('input_radio');

input.addEventListener('focus', () => {
  inputRadio[1].checked = 1;
})

input.addEventListener('blur', () => {
  if (input.value == '') {
    inputRadio[0].checked = 1;
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="some" class="some">
  <label for="some">Заголовок</label>
  <p>
    <label>
           <input type="radio" class="input_radio" name="some_radio" 
           checked="checked" /> 
           <span class="radio-custom"></span>
        <span class="label">Выбрать 0</span>
     </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" class="input_radio" name="some_radio"/> 
     <span class="radio-custom"></span>
     <span class="label">Выбрать 1 </span>
        <input type="text" class="input" name="price" value="">
    </label>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: сработало. Но если установить первую кнопку, а затем нажать на поле, то уже не срабатывает.